# Trying to understand the Visual Studio Memory Analyzer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2013

I appear to have a memory leak since a lot of it won't be disposed, in the image you can see that from point #1 to 2# only 1MB gets added according to the snapshot, yet in the graph it appears to be 110MB. How come there is so much difference.

Also when I look through the objects I don't see any major memory usings even with the filters disabled. 
How can I the identify the memory?

Note: I'm working with Windows Phone 8.1 RT
[image]

Update: I made a Universal sample project for VS2013 Update 3, please have a look and thanks in advance: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DF7008EF9AB1AE2E%21110355

Sample memory usage:
[image]

Comment: Private bytes just doesn't have a lot to do with .NET objects.  The world is unmanaged, including those nice looking bitmaps you use.  As long as you can't show us a triangle heading straight towards 2 GB you don't have a real problem, just a misunderstanding how the machine actually works.  Yes, an uncomfortable view.

Comment: To bad this is still a problem, the memory limit is 180MB (the red line) on Windows Phone 8.1 RT and when I open the item page 1 more time it will crash